# Docker Swarm Services

Tags: docker

I have 2 node in docker swarm one manager and other worker. 
When created a service of jenkins on manager node and running "docker service ps jenkins" shows service running on manager node but if purposely making manager to shutdown to check whether service has started on worker node verifying fault tolerant performance. But the issue is service doesn't starts on worker node.
Executing "docker ps" on worker does not shows any container running on worker node.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You haven't given us a lot to go on here .. Maybe you could make your question more detailed, outlining the exact commands you ran, and their respective outputs

Answer (score 0):

With a 2 node cluster, you have no HA. For HA in swarm mode, you need 3 managers, which allows 1 to fail and the other two continue to schedule jobs on the remaining nodes.

If you have a job running on a single manager, and shutdown that manager, there's nothing left to reschedule that job, so you won't see it run on the worker.

For more details, see the swarm mode documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/nodes/